# Бот на ноде сохранение сообщений

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот

```js
function newMessage(message, text) {
  let chatids = chat[message].chatid;
  console.log('Получил чат ид ' + chatids);

  let chatidsss = require('./chat/chat_' + chatids + '.json');
  console.log('Прочитал файл' + chatidsss);

  let newText = chatidsss.messages += `[${text}]\n`;
  console.log('Получил сообщение');

  console.log(newText);

  console.log(chatidsss.id);
  require('fs').writeFileSync('./chat/chat_' + chatids + '.json', JSON.stringify(newText, null, '\t'));
  console.log('Сохранил сообщение');
  return true

}
```

UPD:

```
        let id = user; //Тот кто отправил сообщение
    let message = text; //текст сообщение
    let chats = chat_id;//Беседа

    //let chatids = chat[chats].chatid; //Получаем беседу
    var chatidsss = require('./chat_'+chats+'.json'); //Получаем файл беседы
    let newText = `${id}: ${message}`; //Записываем сообщение в переменную
    chatidsss.messages.push(newText); //Записываем сообщение в файл
    require('fs').writeFileSync('./Spokers/chat/chat_'+chats+'.json', JSON.stringify(chatidsss, null, '\t')); //Сохраним файл
```

Получаю сообщение и чат айди беседы.
Пытаюсь сохранить в файле и получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, при запросе json файла с чатом, у вас ошибка синтаксиса в самом файле. К слову не совсем понятно зачем вы переписываете файлы, как по мне, проще поднять базу данных.

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупые ошибки, только начал писать на ноде. Создаётся файл Chat_# за место # номер чата. Теперь нужно записывать все(либо онли команды) чатов. По большей части думаю что у меня ошибка в получение данных из чата

Comment: У вас ошибка конкретно на строке "require('./chat/chat_' + chatids + '.json')". Ошибка говорит, что он имеет проблемы с синтаксисом. Ну а конкретно для записей и используется бд. Ее довольно просто развернуть с помощью докера.

Comment: А можно примерно рассказать что за "докер"

Comment: Что такое докер вы уж соизвольте погуглить сами, а как запустить с его помощью базу, можете посмотреть например в моем репозитории https://github.com/MrYogurt/chat-app/blob/master/docker-compose-db.yml. Затем просто добавляем скрипт запуска в package.json ""db": "docker-compose -f docker-compose-db.yml up"" и запускаем. Дело буквально минут на 15. Для запросов к базе советую использовать либу typeorm, которая позволит общаться с бд через простой js синтаксис.

Comment: Больше похоже что это MSQL скрипты, но задам вопрос по другому, как мне прочитать данный файл

Comment: Вопрос мне не понятен, я дал вам ссылку на файл, который можно просто скопировать и запустить как я написал, предварительно установив докер и база будет запущена.

Comment: Я пытаюсь прочитать на данный момент 2 файла chat_2 и chat_3 можно как-то парсировать? JSON.parse ругается на синтакс тоже

Comment: Значит у вас просто не json.

Comment: Есть решение этой проблемы пришёл к ней сам.